# Disabling the session tracker for non HTML templates

Tags: freemember, sessions, tracking

I have a problem with DevDemon FreeMember where it relies on the native EE session tracker array (https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#tracker-array) to perform a "Return to Previous Page'. From mod.freemember.php:

```
protected function history($id)
{
    $tracker = ee()->session->tracker;

    if (isset($tracker[$id])) {
        if ($tracker[$id] === 'index') {
            return '/';
        }

        return $tracker[$id];
    }
}
```

If on the page prior to calling the FreeMember log-in form with the return parameter set to PREVIOUS_URL I have a template which references an ExpressionEngine CSS template then the 'Previous URL' is recorded in the session tracker as the CSS file and not the last 'page' viewed by the user.

Is there some way I can disable session tracking for a single particular front end template as to negate this issue?

*Update*

Solved. I had the EE template I was using for my dynamic CSS set as a standard template, not a CSS template. The template parser in EE actually prevents JS and CSS templates from being added to the tracker array. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had the EE template I was using for my dynamic CSS set as a standard template, not a CSS template. The template parser in EE actually prevents JS and CSS templates from being added to the tracker array. :)